# How to give control from a form in a tab to another tab in a tab panel?

Tags: php, jquery

I have tab panel. I have a form in the first tab in the tab panel. I want to fill all the contents in the form in the first tab panel, and the control should go to the second tab. I dnt how to do it in jquery.

This is the tab structure :

```
      <div class="wizard-inner">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">Customer
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2"> Person
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3"> Equipment
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step4" role="tab" title="Step 4"> Address
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete"> Cart
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

form in the first tab :

```
<form name="customer" id="customer" method="post" action="#step2">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="pad col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Gender</label>
                                    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="dropselectsec1" required>
                                                    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Skill level</label>
                                    <select name="visa_status" id="g" class="r" required>
                                                    <option value="">Select Skill level</option>
                                                    <option value="df">cv</option>
                                                    <option value="df">xc</option>
                                                    <option value="df">df</option>
                                                </select>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group col-md-12 inc">

                                </div>  


                                </div>
                                <div class="pad col-md-6">
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fg</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Age" required>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fgf</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="height" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Height * (cm)" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fgfg</label>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Weight * (kg)" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ffg</label>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shoesize" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Shoe size *" required>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary next-step" value="Continue"/>

                             </form>
```

After filling all the details in the form, I want to give the control to the second tab. How to give it in jquery ? Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: You want to just move form from tab1 to tab2?

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/2aQ2g/54/ This example will help you in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Call below function in button click

```
function ValidData()
{
    var $myForm = $('#customer');        
    if ($myForm[0].checkValidity()) {            
        //Activate next tab code goes here
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form in each step, load the page and set a variable in javascript to indicate the current step.  Then use that to set the correct tab disable all tabs, then activate the correct one.

So something like this:

```
<?php
// logic to determine current step...
$step = 'step1'; // or 'step2', 'step3', etc
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    var current_step = <?php echo $step; ?>;
    // reset all li elements under any div that has a "wizard-inner" class 
    $('div.wizard-inner li').removeClass('active').addClass('disabled');

    // set the correct tab as active.  you'd have to add an this id to the appropriate DOM element
    $('#step1-tab').addClass('active');
})
</script>

<?php
// more php code
?>
```

It's a little unclear how your actual page is put together since you haven't posted all your code, but that's the gist of a solution.  You'll probably want to add ids, names, data attributes, etc to certain DOM elements to make them easier to identify and interact with, with javascript.